# Keep buttons and form with select dropdown on same row in Bootstrap 3

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling to keep buttons, and a form with a `<select>` tag (including its label) all on the same row in Bootstrap 3. Whenever the form is rendered, it seems to add a line break before the form. Here's what I have put together so far (http://www.bootply.com/98022):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Test 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default">Test 2</button>
      <form role="form" class="form-inline">      
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectUser">Select:</label>
        <select id="selectUser" class="form-control selectWidth">
          <option class="">One</option>
          <option class="">Two</option>
          <option class="">Three</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Test 3</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div> <!-- End Row -->
</div> <!-- End Container -->
```

I thought that the `class="form-inline"` would keep it on the same row. Unfortunately, this is how it renders:

[image: The form is rendering on a separate line instead of staying on the same line/row]

This is a mock-up I created in an image editing program of what I'd like it to look like:

[image: This is a mock-up of how I'd like the buttons to display]

I have deliberately chosen to use the `<select>` element instead of Bootstrap dropdowns, as the interface on mobile devices is optimal (the list will be quite large and trying to select the correct option on a small screen is easier with a form `<select>` element).

I found similar questions, but most either don't address the `<select>` tag within a form, or are for older versions of Bootstrap (2.x). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first two button are not inside the `form` tag.

It seems `form-inline` does not define styles for labels, so add a left float some padding and set the width of the select to auto.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <form role="form" class="form-inline">  
      <button class="btn btn-default">Test 1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default">Test 2</button>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectUser" style="float:left;padding: 6px 12px 2px 12px;">Select:</label>
        <select id="selectUser" style="width:auto;" class="form-control selectWidth">
          <option class="">One</option>
          <option class="">Two</option>
          <option class="">Three</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Test 3</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div> <!-- End Row -->
</div> <!-- End Container -->
```

Comment: Thanks Bass! It appears that simply including the buttons inside of the `<form>` tag made everything appear on the same line (updated: http://www.bootply.com/98089). Is there any problem with including multiple buttons within the form, even though they are unrelated to the actual form itself? Also, I did not have to add the left float to the label as it appears to align itself with `class="form-inline"`. Thank you!

Comment: yw, i will check the label with `class="form-inline"` and update my answer if i found something different, see also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11531

Comment: you can use form-inline with a div too, works like a charm :) :)

Comment: I know this is an inline form, but....Please do **NOT** use inline styles! This is not maintainable. Add a class and define the styles there.